# addEvent doesn't work with chrome 25 and OSX

Tags: google-chrome, mootools, addeventlistener

I've a problem only with chrome 25 and osx.

I get results with this line

```
console.log($$('.sort-box-slt-pl-opt'));
```

But with this lines

```
$$('.sort-box-slt-pl-opt').addEvent('click', function(event){
    console.log('test');
});
```

the code inside the addEvent handler is never reached.

Did anyone have the same problem ?

I'm working with mootools 1.4, but the same problem happen when i try to use document.getElementsByClassName

thanks.

---

thank you for your comment but i still have the same trouble.
this is my html structure:

```
<span id="ead-sort-box-select-bloc">
    <select id="ead-sort-box-select" class="divid-slt___cdc_" name="sort-box-ead">
        <option class="sort-box-slt-pl-opt sort-box-slt-pl-opt-asc" value="functions/ead/mosaic-results.ajax-html?base=ead&champ1=fulltext&op1=AND&search_type=simple&query1=sdxall%3A1&ssearch-submit-npt.x=0&ssearch-submit-npt.y=0&form-display-only-media=&docs=true&&skippage=here&sf=&so=asc">pertinence</option>
        <option class="sort-box-slt-pl-opt sort-box-slt-pl-opt-asc" value="functions/ead/mosaic-results.ajax-html?base=ead&champ1=fulltext&op1=AND&search_type=simple&query1=sdxall%3A1&ssearch-submit-npt.x=0&ssearch-submit-npt.y=0&form-display-only-media=&docs=true&&skippage=here&sf=fucomptitle&so=asc">titre croissant</option>
        <option class="sort-box-slt-pl-opt sort-box-slt-pl-opt-desc" value="functions/ead/mosaic-results.ajax-html?base=ead&champ1=fulltext&op1=AND&search_type=simple&query1=sdxall%3A1&ssearch-submit-npt.x=0&ssearch-submit-npt.y=0&form-display-only-media=&docs=true&&skippage=here&sf=fucomptitle&so=desc">titre décroissant</option>
        <option> .... </option>
    </select>
<span>
```

I want to execute an ajax function when the user select an option but, the code inside the addEvent is never reached. This is the JS code:

```
...
if(Browser.chrome && Browser.Platform.mac){
    if($('ead-sort-box-select') != null){
        var elements = $$('.sort-box-slt-pl-opt');
        elements.each( function( element ) {
            element.addEvent('click', function(){
                console.log('test');
            });
        });
    }
}
...
```

Comment: Well - it's looks ok: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MdMFe/)
Show us the full code

Comment: https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/scripts-breakpoints#listeners and also https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/commandline-api#monitoreventsobject_events (monitorEvents). you can see if an element has a mootools event by doing `console.log(el.retrieve('events')['keys']);`